# What's the difference between """ and ''' in terms of running a shell script within a Jenkins pipeline step?

Tags: groovy, dsl, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins pipeline, what's the difference between:

```
sh """
...
...
... 
"""
```

and

```
sh '''
...
...
... 
'''
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Both are multi-line strings

The first multi-line string with `"""` [can be templated into a GroovyString](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_double_quoted_string)

The second one with `'''` cannot ([and is just a java String with newlines](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_single_quoted_string))

I have linked to the relevant documentation

Comment: Yes, triple double quoted strings support variable interpolation/substitution when triple simple quoted strings don't.