# Jenkins groovy escape #

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have been trying to get the remove "origin" from branch name in JenkinsFile sh script using

```
 steps {
                sh """#!/bin/bash 
                echo '${GIT_BRANCH\#*/}'
                """
 }
```

I have tried replacing it with based on other suggestions but did not succeed.

```
"${GIT_BRANCH\#*/}" "${GIT_BRANCH#*/}" '${GIT_BRANCH\#*/}' '${GIT_BRANCH#*/}'
```

All come with error:

```
WorkflowScript: 80: unexpected char: '#' @ line 80, column 38.
                       echo ${GIT_BRANCH#*/}
```

or

```
WorkflowScript: 80: unexpected char: '\' @ line 80, column 38.
                       echo ${GIT_BRANCH\#*/}
```

Running in Jenkins jenkins/jenkins:2.418
Any hints?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but have you tried ${GIT_BRANCH}/#.*

Comment: I am trying to stip "origin\" from branch name this you do using bash  command ${var_name#*/} that would get "b_name" from "origin/b_name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do the following.

```bash
sh'''
  result=${GIT_BRANCH#*/}
  echo "Result: $result"
'''
```

Comment: Thanks @ycr . It worked. Found more explanation here if anyone gets same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333715/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-terms-of-running-a-shell-script-wit