# How to replace substring in jenkins pipeline step?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am able to replace substring in bash with below command. However, same command doesn't work in Jenkins pipeline shell script inside the step. Basically, in Jenkins ${GIT_BRANCH} returns 'origin/docker'. I want to use branch name 'docker' in URL while uploading deployment artifact to JFrog artifactory. However, I do not want to include 'origin/' string in the path.

Working Bash Command:

```
user@localhost MINGW64 ~
$ echo $GIT_BRANCH
origin/docker

user@localhost MINGW64 ~
$ GIT_BRANCH_NAME="${GIT_BRANCH/origin\/}"

user@localhost MINGW64 ~
$ echo $GIT_BRANCH_NAME
docker
```

Jenkins File Script:

```
GIT_BRANCH_NAME="${GIT_BRANCH/origin\/}"
```

The error I am seeing in Jenkins pipeline execution logs:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:    
WorkflowScript: 38: unexpected char: '\' @ line 38, column 53.
       ANCH_NAME="${GIT_BRANCH/origin\/}
```

Adding working script block. Now the env variable 'GIT_BRANCH_NAME' returns just 'docker' instead of 'origin/docker'. Also, added few more statements to handle various types of branches like 'bugfix/feature/hotfix/release' etc.

```
script {
env.GIT_BRANCH_NAME=""
String gitBranchName = env.GIT_BRANCH.replaceFirst('^origin/', '')
env.GIT_BRANCH_NAME = gitBranchName.replaceFirst('^bugfix/', 'bugfix-')
env.GIT_BRANCH_NAME = gitBranchName.replaceFirst('^feature/', 'feature-')
env.GIT_BRANCH_NAME = gitBranchName.replaceFirst('^hotfix/', 'hotfix-')
env.GIT_BRANCH_NAME = gitBranchName.replaceFirst('^release/', 'release-')
}
```

```bash
sh '''
    mv ${GIT_COMMIT}.zip app_${GIT_BRANCH_NAME}_${GIT_COMMIT}.zip
    curl -u JFROG_USR:JFROG_PSW -T app_${GIT_BRANCH_NAME}_${GIT_COMMIT}.zip "some-jfrog-artifctory-url/${BUILD_NUMBER}/app_${GIT_BRANCH_NAME}_${GIT_COMMIT}.zip;git.branch.name=${GIT_BRANCH};git.commit.id=${GIT_COMMIT};jenkins.build.url=${BUILD_URL}"
    rm -rf app_${GIT_BRANCH_NAME}_${GIT_COMMIT}.zip
'''
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77004560/2627018

Comment: Please show a wider context of the code as presented in the pipeline. Is this a `sh` block? is it wrapped in \`\`\` characters, or one of the other methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547680/how-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-using-into-a-variable-from-j)? Is it because `ANCH_NAME="${GIT_BRANCH/origin\/}` doesn't close the quotes? Are you sure it's actually using a `bash`-like shell that understands that syntax? (Not meaning to rapid fire questions to sound like I'm interrogating you - just hoping one will trigger a useful "aha" moment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jenkins file in `script` block, You've groovy language, so you are able to use groovy semantic.

So if you are in the `script` block context, you can remove prefix and set up new environment variable:

```
String gitBranchName = env.GIT_BRANCH.replaceFirst('^origin/', '')
withEnv(["GIT_BRANCH_NAME=${gitBranchName}"]) {
   ...                
}
```

Comment: Updated the script block as mentioned in the updated part of the question and it started working.